# Excel VBA pull single value out of range and put into a cell

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

The following code works sometimes and sometimes not:

```vb
Sub anothertest()
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As String
    'vArray = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit")
    With ActiveSheet
        vArray = Range("G2:G10").Value
    End With
    x = UBound(vArray) - LBound(vArray) + 1
    MsgBox x
    y = vArray(1)
    MsgBox y
    Cells(1, 10).Value = y
End Sub
```

It works with `vArray = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit")`, returning `x` as `3` and `y` as `Dog`.
However, if I comment that out and activate `With Activesheet` to `End With`, it rightly returns `x` as `9` but returns a `Runtime error 9, script out of range`, even though it will print the full range correctly in a `for each` loop.
I need the sub to work with the range argument.  It works perfectly elsewhere in my script where I use `for each` loops, but here I need to pick one value out of the range per sheet.  Also, I am curious as to why it does not work, if I run into the problem again.

Comment: `Range(...).Value` returns a 2D array (even if the range is only one column (or row)), in your case `9x1`.  Access elements by specifying both dimensions, eg `y = vArray(1,1)`

Comment: Here you can use `vArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("G2:G10").Value)` so you get Variant 1D Array (1 To 9).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
 Sub anothertest()
     Dim vArray() As Variant
     Dim x As Integer
     Dim y As Variant
     With ActiveSheet
        vArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("G2:G10").Value) 
     End With
     x = UBound(vArray) - LBound(vArray) + 1
     MsgBox x
     y = vArray(1)
     MsgBox y
     Cells(1, 10).Value = y
 End Sub
```